# ¿Por que solo 72 caracteres en Direccion Relativa?

Tags: c, makefile

Utilizo esta direccion relativa:

```
DEBUG = -I$(INCLUDE0) -L$(LIBS0) -lxxx_xxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxxxxx_xxxx_xxxxx_xx
INCLUDE0 = ../../../../../xxxxxxx/xxx_xxxxxxxxx/xxx_xxxxxxxxx_xxxxx/xxx_xxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxxxxx_xxxx/xxx_xxxxxxxx_xxxx_xxxxxx_xxxx_xxxxxx_xx/xxxxxxx
```

Y no funciona me dice que no encuentra el archivo de cabecera,
ahora utilizo esta direccion absoluta,

```
INCLUDE0 = x:/xxxxxxx\ xxx/xxxxxxx/xxx_xxxxxxxxx/xxx_xxxxxxxxx_xxxxx/xxx_xxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxxxxx_xxxx/xxx_xxxxxxxx_xxxx_xxxxxx_xxxx_xxxxxx_xx/xxxxxxx
```

Y todo compila de maravilla,

ahora probé y sólo puedo colocar en la direccion relativa 72 caracteres, y compila de maravilla

```
INCLUDE0 = ../../../../../xxxxxxx/xxx_xxxxxxxxx/xxx_xxxxxxxxx_xxxxx/xxx_xxxxxxxx_
```

¿Qué es lo que realmente pasa aquí?, no he investigado todavia pero en debian no pasa esto.

Datos adicionales: gcc10+, msys2, notepad

Gracias por los comentarios.

Gracias por responder, estos son los verificados segun tu comentario

```
DEBUG = -g -ggdb -fPIC \
        -I$(INCLUDE1) -L$(LIBS0) -lmdl_crud_database_mysql_extend_00 \
        -I$(INCLUDE2) -L$(LIBS1) -lmysql
INCLUDE0 = ../../../../../Models/mdl_crud/mdl_crud_database/mdl_crud_database_mysql/mdl_crud_database_mysql_extend_00/include
INCLUDE1 = C:/Source\ Inc/Models/mdl_crud/mdl_crud_database/mdl_crud_database_mysql/mdl_crud_database_mysql_extend_00/include
LIBS0 = ../../../../../bin/libs
INCLUDE2 = ../../../../../resources/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64/include
LIBS1 =  ../../../../../resources/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64/lib
```

solo cambia el INCLUDE1 por el INCLUDE0 y sigue sin funcionar

Este es el mensaje de consola:

```
> make
gcc -c src/main.c -o obj/main.o \
    -g -ggdb -fPIC \
    -I../../../../../Models/mdl_crud/mdl_crud_database/mdl_crud_database_mysql/mdl_crud_database_mysql_extend_00/include \
    -L../../../../../bin/libs -lmdl_crud_database_mysql_extend_00 -I../../../../../resources/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64/include \
    -L../../../../../resources/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64/lib \
    -lmysql                         
In file included from src/main.c:2:                                                         
src/../include/ctrl_mdl_crud_database_mysql_extend_00.h:3:10: 
fatal error: mdl_crud_database_mysql_extend_00.h: 
No such file or directory                                                   
3 | #include "mdl_crud_database_mysql_extend_00.h"                                            
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                      
compilation terminated.                                                                     
make: *** [Makefile:16: obj/main.o] Error 1                                                 
PS C:\Source Inc\Controllers\ctrl_mdl_crud\ctrl_mdl_crud_database\ctrl_mdl_crud_database_mysql\ctrl_mdl_crud_database_mysql_extend_00>
```

Gracias por las apreciaciones finales

Comment: Los nombres de sus subdirectorios no son los mismos<br>
En el relativo tienes `xxx_xxxxxxxx_xxxx_xxxxxx_xxxx_xxxxxx_xx` : 33 `x`<br>
En el absoluto tienes `xxx_xxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxxxxx_xxxx_xxxxxx_xx` : 34 `x`<br>
Puedes montrar los commandos y  mesajes de error real ?<br>

Comment: Hola, amplie el tema como me dijistes. Este mismo codigo en Debian trabaja sin la mensionada ruta absoluta, pero en window no lo hace; así que lo solucione con la ruta absoluta y continue trabajando y me quedo la duda de los 72 caracteres en este, No solamente aquí, en parte del mismo proyecto aparece lo mismo así que hice lo de la ruta absoluta y continué trabajando. Un saludo

Comment: Es decir, esto es gcc en WSL sobre Windows? Lo otro que revisaría no es la ruta relativa (72 o 71 carácteres o los que sean) sino la ruta total que resulta al incluir archivos especificos, porque ahí en windows va a pelear si se pasa de 260